Node JS Express - Download window doesn't appear until all file is sent in header response
I'm working with Express to create an api that allow to download a PDF file.
Download is working fine, but I don't see the download window where I choose the folder I want to download, until all "download" is done in network connection.

This pdf is 22Mb.
Here's part of my code:
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, serverPath.replace(/[/\\]/g, path.sep))
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath)

fileStream
    .on('error', (error) => {
        next(error) // --> Send error to middleWare
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        logger.info(`${order} - File:${pathDB.fileName} from ${filePath} correctly Downloaded`)
    })

// send file in https response, "blob" type
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + pathDB.fileName)
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
fileStream.pipe(res)

I've tried adding Content-Length but doesn't work.
const stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
const fileSize = stat.size;

res.setHeader('Content-Length', fileSize); // Set the Content-Length header

How should I manage it to allow user to select download folder before all pdf is downloaded?
For example, I've seen in AMD drivers website, when you click to download response sent a 200b object, popup the download window, and when you accept, the whole file is downloaded.
https://www.amd.com/en/support/download/drivers.html
EDIT
I've changed code to use Express Helper, and now I have it:
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, serverPath.replace(/[/\\]/g, path.sep))
res.download(filePath, pathDB.fileName, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    next(error) // Send error to middleware
  } else {
    // Log success if file download is successful
    logger.info(`${order} - File:${pathDB.fileName} from ${filePath} correctly Downloaded`)
  }
})

I still having the same problem. I'm seeing differences between AMD response headers and mine.
AMD:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
ETag: "3e08a86b5c7c644f5903198261cf2277:1714054955.870475"
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Apr 2024 22:04:07 GMT
Server: AkamaiNetStorage
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Fri, 10 May 2024 07:14:16 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Content-Encoding-Over-Network: gzip

My API:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
RateLimit-Limit: 100
RateLimit-Remaining: 99
RateLimit-Reset: 869
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myPDF.pdf"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Thu, 09 May 2024 13:17:05 GMT
Date: Fri, 10 May 2024 07:20:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
ETag: W/"93dc3f-18f5d80126d"
Content-Length: 9690175


This Is Because You Are Trying To Stream The Data, The Data Are Coming In Chunks And Getting Stored In Clients Browser-Cache, Then Joining And Asking For Storage Location, Like It Works Similar When You Are Downloading Files From mega.io
To Make Your API Download The Data, Use This:-
res.download("pdf_name.pdf")

Or You Can Use sendFile() Instead. It Is Only Built To Send Data From A File, Not From Memory. So It Is Not Memory Intensive But Can Be CPU Intensive For Server During High Upload Rate Which Can Be Limited, Check This -> link
